# Set ECHO / TYPE output as a Variable in Batch Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to set the output of TYPE or ECHO as a variable in a batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convoluted, and it only works for a single line, but general:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('some command with output') do set "Var=%%x"
```

For `echo` you don't need to do anything special, just change

```
echo Foo
```

into

```
set Var=Foo
```

And for files there is also the option of either

```
set /p Var=<file.txt
```

or

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do set "Var=%%x"
```

Comment: Could this be done for the type command? (Baring in mind the text file only has 1 line)

Comment: what about for a multi-line file?

Comment: @Ceekay, you can keep a counter and emulate an array with numbered environment variables.